# what does the data file look like in sorted-based shuffle？

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

Recently, there are some problems about sorted-based shuffle that have been bothering me：
1.How many files does the shuffle write process produce？2*cores or 2*tasks？
2.sorted-based shuffle will produce two types of files：data file and index file,so what does the data file looks like? Can you show me an example?
3.How many partitionID are generated in the dataFile? Based on what to generate partitionID? Will each task generate the same range of partitionID?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you call the "sorted-based suffle" is the `SortShuffleWriter`.

1. The shuffle write process produces 2 files for each `ShuffleMapTask`, One is an index file and another is the data file. There can be temporary spill files that are generated during the process. However, only two files are finally kept per each task. Thus the number of files should be 2*tasks.
2. The index file contains offset information for reading a particular partition from the data file. These offsets are written as `Long` and calculated from the lengths of partitions. The data file contains all the partitions and the data for each partition is separate within the file. That is the elements of partitions are not interleaved.
3. The number of partition Id depends on the partitioner and the range of partition Id generated by tasks may vary.

Comment: I have not seen any evidence of merging data or index files across tasks. As I said there may be temporary spill files during the shuffle process of a task and they are merged but not shuffle output files of different tasks. The shuffle read process probably will need to read number of tasks*2 files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have some confusion:1.So the number of files for each executor would be 2*tasks after the shuffleWrite? I mean, will these data files(or index files) merge together ?  Will the shuffle read process read the number of 2*tasks files in one executor？   3.why the range of partition Id may vary? Does it not to find the same partition id duing the shuffle read process? Look forward to your reply.